# Simple jquery ajax vs SignalR vs AspComet

Tags: comet, long-polling, signalr

I'm reading about long polling, comet etc and, working on .Net, I read all I have found about SignalR and AspComet. I'm a newbie about comet & similar but it is not clear to me what are the advantages in using SignalR or AspComet where i can simply use jquery.ajax/complete:

```
(function poll(){
    $.ajax({ url: "server", success: function(data){
       doSomething();    
    }, dataType: "json", complete: poll, timeout: 30000 });
})();
```

but I am clearly missing something here, can you help?

Also, from a system/server point of view what are the main differences? I understand that with $.ajax I open a connection to the server and keep it opened for long (with all the disadvantages of too many open simultaneous connection etc) but I assume SignalR does the same. Or not?
While, on this, AspComet says that it releases the thread back to the request pool.

I know, I'm a bit confused and an intro about the advantages to use SignalR and/or AspComet vs the $.ajax stuff would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In your `$.ajax` example you are sending multiple requests to the server and you are doing this for each client. So your web server gets constantly hammered by HTTP requests and only few of them actually serve a purpose because the data that clients have subscribed to notifications for might not change as often. As long as one AJAX request completes another one is sent immediately.

Whereas with long polling you are sending a single request which is blocked by the server and allows it to write to the response and thus notify the client.

The advantage of long polling is that you are limiting the number of HTTP requests sent to your server.

Comment: I took that example from a [blog](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery) and they say just one request is sent to the server until it is complete (recursive call poll again). The example should be long-polling. I misquoted anything?

Answer (score 2):

COMET applications often require a custom server. IIS keeps a dedicated thread to handle each request which obviously doesn't scale. There is a limit of a few thousand threads per CPU in IIS.

AspComet solves this problem by providing a server side solution to handle the thread lifetime (like you wrote, it returns the threads back to the pool). AspComet is compatible with the [Bayeux Protocol](http://svn.cometd.org/trunk/bayeux/bayeux.html) so you can use any Bayeux JS client.

SignalR is a client/server solution that encapsulates the underlying communication protocol in asynchronous calls. SignalR chooses the best protocol available (long polling, websockets or other) so you don't need to worry about it. They have clients for .NET, Silverlight, WP7, JS, etc.

Comment: thanks! Things start to get clearer. As I host our app in a multi instances environment, SignalR can't be used yet as it doesn't work properly if there's more than one instance of the app. I wonder if AspComet is multi-instances friendly or not. Any ideas?

Comment: @Pietro Sorry, but I never used AspComet. I know that the SignalR team is working on that though.

Comment: I know I'm late to the party, but I'd like to add my 2 cents re multi-instance. AspComet doesn't support multi-instance out of the box, at least if you're using the sample configuration, since it stores the client repository in-memory. You could persist the client repository some other way that could be shared across instances, but performance might degrade due to latency or locking contention. What we ended up doing is using a load balancer to direct comet requests to a particular instance. Looks like they were working on a redis store for signalr, but it may have been abandoned?